# Test vectors for LTE kasme generation in authentication

Tags: authentication, lte

I am working on LTE authentication framework and have written an EPS-AKA algorithm to generate KASME. 
However, I dont have any sample to test it. Can someone provide me any reference of test vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still working on this, but the following link should answer your question: http://fabricioapps.blogspot.com/2012/05/lte-security.html

Using this person's application discussed in the link above, it appears that you can generate the vectors you are looking for. The screenshot below demonstrates some of the functionality, however there is much more than what I have shown here. If you have further questions, I would recommend contacting the author of the application directly (fasferraz at gmail dot com).

[image]